# Having Some Error With Htaccess when i adding dot operator to it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have two files one is php handler.php file and second one is a htaccess that working fine without .(dot) but when we add dot to its just echo handler.php

book/handler.php exist in book dir

```
<?php
echo $_GET['bookid'];
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# i added 2 line one for book/abc and secon for book/abc/

RewriteRule ^book/([a-z-A-Z-0-9-.]+)$ book/handler.php?bookid=$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^book/([a-z-A-Z-0-9-/]+)/ book/handler.php?bookid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

when i submit localhost/book/handler.php?bookid=somthing.php
it return handler.php

check out this url for demo
[link](https://gamingchamp.000webhostapp.com/book/deepak)
when i add book/somthing or book/somthing.php it return handler.php

Comment: Is user putting `localhost/book/handler.php?bookid=somthing.php` in browser or its internal redirect from one internal url to another? Because usually user friendly urls are recommended to be given to users, kindly confirm once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/handler\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /book/([^\s]*)\s+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book/handler.php?%1 [NE,NC,L]
```

***Explanation:***

- `RewriteEngine ON`: Making `RewriteEngine` on here so that mod rewrite rules are enabled.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/handler\.php [NC]`: To avoid looping here, so that once redirection happens it should get failed in this, while coming after successful redirection.
- `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /book/([^\s]*)\s+ [NC]`: In default variable  `THE_REQUEST` using regex to match string `book` saving everything into first backreference so that could be used later in redirection part.
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book/handler.php?%1 [NE,NC,L]`: Performing actual redirection(internal one) by passing `/book/handler.php` with value of 1st backreference here. Using flags `NE`, `NC` and `L` make redirection smooth.